# SQL converter varchar to Timestamp 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS#Z' format to 'HH:MM:SS'

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, time, type-conversion

I have a dataset/table in SQLite with this format '2022-02-21T17:36:48.311Z' varchar and I would like to convert it to Timestamp creating two others new columns one for date/day values'YYYY-MM-DD' and another with the "hours" values HH:MM:SS.

I tried:

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'),  'YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM:SS')
from table
```

but it does not work.

The column_name is a varchar dataformat, and as example of value from this column are

```
2022-02-21T07:22:46.777Z
2022-02-21T07:22:57.877Z
2022-02-21T07:23:27.362Z
2022-02-21T07:23:28.212Z
```

Any suggestion ? The idea is to "break" this column_name into two another columns, one with days and the other with hours values.

Comment: There are no Timestamp or datetime or date data types in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Use string functions like SUBSTR() to split the column values in 2 parts since their length is fixed, or use datetime functions like DATE() and TIME().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select (substr(d, 1, 4) || '-' || substr(d, 6, 2) || '-' || substr(d, 9, 2)) as DateVal,
(substr(d, 12, 2) || ':' || substr(d, 15, 2) || ':' || substr(d, 18, 2)) as TimeVal
from Dates;
```

Or

```
select Date(d) as DateVal, Time(d) as TimeVal from Dates;
```

See a demo using `SQLite v3.30` from ***[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/apcBuK11fnM8MVSHYuvpfN/0)***.